# Asynchronous function calls in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, asynchronous

I'm pretty new to `Qt` and programming and are facing a problem I can't find a solution for.

I want to read some information from an online XML file and send it to my main program.

To do so, I created a class XMLParser and added the following to the constructor:

```
XMLParser::XMLParser(QString searchstring)
{
    QNetworkAccessManager *manager2 = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    reply = manager2->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://www.boardgamegeek.com/xmlapi/search?search="+searchstring)));

    XMLParser::connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()),
                   this, SLOT(fileIsReady()) );
}
```

and `fileIsReady` fills a QMap and stores it as a private class member.

In my second class, I call

```
  XMLParser *xmlpars = new XMLParser(input_gamename->text());
  QMap<QString, int> searchResults = xmlpars->getSearchList();
```

and getSearchList is a simple getter function.

The problem is, that getSearchList is executed before fileIsReady finished reading the XML file and returns an empty map.
From what I understand, the constructor should not be finished until `fileIsReady()` finished its work. And thus, getSearchList() shouldn't be called early.

My two questions:

1. Why does my programm progresses while the function didn't finish reading.
2. How can I make the second call "getSearchList" wait?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to understand the fundamental concept of signals and slots.

After you make a connection, the slot will get called every time the signal is emitted.

The `connect()` functions returns after connecting the signal to the slot. It doesn't wait for the signal to be emitted.

In your XMLParser constructor, your `connect()` function registers this: "When the `finished()` signal is emitted, run the `fileIsReady()` function".

Now, to answer your questions.

> 1. Why does my programm progresses while the function didn't finish reading.

Because in your constructor code, you asked the constructor to finish after you connect the signal to the slot. You did not ask it to wait for the download to finish.

And then, you call getSearchList() without waiting for the finished() signal. So, getSearchList() gets called before fileIsReady().

> 2. How can I make the second call "getSearchList" wait?

Like MrEricSir said, you *shouldn't* ask it to wait! (Think about it: What happens if you lose internet connection and can't finish downloading the file? The answer is, your program will freeze because it will wait forever. That's bad.)

Don't call `getSearchList()` immediately after constructing XMLParser. Instead, make XMLParser emit a "finishedParsing()" signal when it finishes parsing the XML file. Then, make another signal-slot connection: Connect the finishedParsing() signal to a slot that calls getSearchList().

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! Helped to understand what's going on. Is there any way to say: Let's wait until all signals (or a list of signals) have been sent? I've implemented another connect, but this could delay the same problem, causing problems at another place. Is it possible to connect the return of a function with such a "finishedReading" signal?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make the second call `getSearchList` wait?

You don't! Instead, just move any code that expect the `XML` file to be downloaded into the `fileIsReady()` slot that you've already defined. That way your program won't lock up while it's waiting for the download to complete (which is the entire point of asynchronous programming.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can't put the getSearchList into the fileIsReady function as I call it from outside to retrieve the output. I think I didn't specify my question.
The constructor waits for the XML File to be ready, but in my second class, getSearchList gets executed before the constructor finished. At least, that's what I think.

Answer (score 1):

So, I found a solution using QEventLoop. But as far as I read, this isn't recommendend.
Are there any other solutions? And why is using QEventLoop bad habit (That's what I read from other answers here StackOverflow).

```
XMLParser::XMLParser(QString searchstring)
{

QNetworkAccessManager *manager2 = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
reply = manager2->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://www.boardgamegeek.com/xmlapi/search?search="+searchstring)));

QEventLoop loop;
XMLParser::connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()),
                   this, SLOT(fileIsReady()) );
XMLParser::connect(this, SIGNAL(finishedReading()),
                   &loop, SLOT(quit()));
loop.exec();

}
```