# Updating class variable Qt signals and slots

Tags: c++, qt, class

I have the following code that populates a QStringList in Qt with c++. When I populate my list in the GetCountriesList slot and try to print the updated QStringList m_CountriesList the list is empty. How can I ensure that the GetCountriesList slot void method worked and print the correct values in the GetIndicatorsList() method.

```
   void MainWindow::GetIndicatorsList()
{
    QNetworkAccessManager *networkManager;
    networkManager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    QUrl url("http://api.worldbank.org/countries?per_page=264&format=json");
    QNetworkReply* reply = networkManager->get(QNetworkRequest(url));
    connect(networkManager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(GetCountriesList(QNetworkReply*)));
    qDebug()<< this->m_CountriesList;

}

void MainWindow::GetCountriesList(QNetworkReply* reply)
{
    if(reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError) {


        QString strReply = (QString)reply->readAll();

        QStringList CountriesList;
        QJsonDocument jsonResponse = QJsonDocument::fromJson(strReply.toUtf8());
        QJsonArray JsonArray = jsonResponse.array();
        JsonArray.removeFirst();

        QJsonArray JsonArray2 = JsonArray[0].toArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < JsonArray2.size(); i++) {
            CountriesList.append(JsonArray2.at(i).toObject().value("name").toString());
         }
        //qDebug() << CountriesList;

        this->m_CountriesList = CountriesList;
        qDebug() << this->m_CountriesList;

        }

     else {
        qDebug() << "ERROR";
    }

}
```

Comment: Add a lot more debugging logs everywhere, or even run the program in a debugger.

Comment: Firstly, are you sure that reply is not empty before you get a json array?

Comment: @someoneinthebox When I print qDebug() << this->m_CountriesList in the GetCountriesList() method I get the desired result, so yes I am sure it is not empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that here:

```
connect(networkManager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(GetCountriesList(QNetworkReply*)));
```

The slot will be called **later**, when the network reply is finished and emits its signal. The `connect` operation is very fast and doesn't wait for the signal to execute, it just creates a connection.

So when you do

```
qDebug()<< this->m_CountriesList;
```

just after the connect, the slot wasn't called **yet**.

The data is simply unavailable at this moment, as the signal wasn't emitted yet and the code to store the countries wasn't executed yet.

This answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27034939/835629 shows you how to handle the situation. Anyway, you can't return the values in your `GetIndicatorsList` right away as that would block the execution of the program for a few seconds, the time to make the network request and get the answer.

You can also give a function or object to call back when the data is ready. [Lambda functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) would probably help you with that.

For example:

```
#include <functional>

void MainWindow::GetIndicatorsList(std::function<void(QStringList)> callback)
{
    if (m_CountriesList.length() > 0) {
         callback(m_CountriesList);
         return;
    }
    QNetworkAccessManager *networkManager;
    networkManager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    QUrl url("http://api.worldbank.org/countries?per_page=264&format=json");
    QNetworkReply* reply = networkManager->get(QNetworkRequest(url));
    connect(networkManager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, [this,callback](QNetworkReply *reply) { 
         if(reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError) {


            QString strReply = (QString)reply->readAll();

            QStringList CountriesList;
            QJsonDocument jsonResponse = QJsonDocument::fromJson(strReply.toUtf8());
            QJsonArray JsonArray = jsonResponse.array();
            JsonArray.removeFirst();

            QJsonArray JsonArray2 = JsonArray[0].toArray();

            for (int i = 0; i < JsonArray2.size(); i++) {
                 CountriesList.append(JsonArray2.at(i).toObject().value("name").toString());
            }
            //qDebug() << CountriesList;

            this->m_CountriesList = CountriesList;
            qDebug() << this->m_CountriesList;
            callback(CountriesList);
        }
        else {
            qDebug() << "ERROR";
        }
    });
}
```

And then you can call it like this:

```
mainWindow->GetIndicatorsList([](QStringList list) {
     qDebug() << "Called back! " << list;
});
```

Comment: Then how can I modify my code to reflect this. A timer perhaps?

Comment: @coyotte508 but how about `qDebug() << this->m_CountriesList;` in `GetCountriesList(QNetworkReply* reply)` slot?

Comment: @JamesDIckens I edited and linked to an answer which suggests to emit a signal when data is ready. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfuture.html can also help you. Read more about asynchroneous tasks, threading and all. An easy solution is not there.

Comment: @someoneinthebox OP said it worked in the slot in a comment, which is normal as that code is executed after the reply was finished.

Comment: @JamesDickens added a code example for the use of lambda functions as a callback